# Tensor products $L_1(\mu)\widetilde{\otimes}_{\pi} L_1(\nu)$ and $L_1(\mu)\widetilde{\otimes}_{\varepsilon} L_1(\nu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products

Can anybody enlighten me, where the tensor products of the spaces of summable functions $L_1(\mu)\widetilde{\otimes}_{\pi} L_1(\nu)$ and $L_1(\mu)\widetilde{\otimes}_{\varepsilon} L_1(\nu)$ are described? (I use the notations $\widetilde{\otimes}_{\pi}$ and $\widetilde{\otimes}_{\varepsilon}$ from the [A.Pietsch book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642876677).) I can't find references. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $L^1(\mu) \tilde\otimes_\pi L^1(\nu)$ is isometrically isomorph (under the canonical isomorphism) to $L^1(\mu \times \nu)$, see, e.g., chapter 7 in Defant & Floret: "Tensor norms and operator ideals".

I do not know whether the space $L^1(\mu) \tilde\otimes_\varepsilon L^1(\nu)$ has an easy description. Maybe you could try first with finite counting measures.